# No such @serializer registered: csv (Plumber)

Tags: r, docker, google-cloud-run, plumber

I am using Plumber on Google Cloud Run through a docker image. Generally, it works fine, but now I am trying to use serializers to send files as attachments but it does not seem to work.

### Dockerfile

This dockerfile is inspired on Mark Edmonson's guide: https://code.markedmondson.me/googleCloudRunner/articles/cloudrun.html

```
FROM trestletech/plumber
RUN export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive; apt-get -y update \
  && apt-get install -y git-core
RUN ["install2.r", "remotes"]
COPY ["./", "./"]
ENTRYPOINT ["R", "-e", "pr <- plumber::plumb(commandArgs()[4]); pr$run(host='0.0.0.0', port=as.numeric(Sys.getenv('PORT')))"]
CMD ["api.R"]
```

(Plumber is installed from `trestletech/plumber` image, that is why it's not in the list of packages;  otherwise, I would use `RUN ["install2.r", "plumber", "remotes"]`)

### R script (excerpt)

```
library(plumber)
#' @post /hello
#' @serializer csv
function(req, res) {

  # <some r code>

  as_attachment(mydataframe, filename = "myfile.csv")
```

## Output

```
No such @serializer registered: csv
```

Comment: Have you took a look on this related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64377801/13171940)?

Comment: See my answer @RogelioMonter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the [Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/trestletech/plumber) I was using was outdated (last update was 3 years ago). I switched to this [another image](https://hub.docker.com/r/rstudio/plumber/) which is up-to-date. This fixed my issue.